# How to make a copy of UIView with all layer properties?

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

I'm making a custom transition for presenting `UINavigationController` from the splash screen, and I should animate only root view controller. I have a `UIStackView` with buttons inside it. Every button and the `UIStackView` has a shadow and layer's property `masksToBounds` set to false. I wrote a custom animator for `UINavigationController` and I was doing all animations there in the method `animateTransition(using transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning)`. When I animate the existing `UIStackView`, I put it into the `containerView` of `transitionContext` and it didn't disappear when other `UIViewController` had been pushed. If I use `removeFromSuperView`, it removes from my `rootViewController` too. I tried to copy `UIStackView` like this:

```
let archive = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: toVC.buttonsStackView)
let buttonsStackViewCopy = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with: archive) as! UIStackView
```

But it doesn't copy layer's property, fonts and other.

Also I tried to render layer into ImageContext like this:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(toVC.buttonsStackView.bounds.size)
let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!
toVC.buttonsStackView.layer.render(in: context)
let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
let buttonsStackViewSnapshot = UIImageView(image: image)
```

The first problem was that the shadows were cut like using simple snapshot of `UIView`. The second problem was when I tried to increase context size. It was everything ok with shadows, but I couldn't calculate right `UIImageView.frame` to make right animation.

Is there any solution how to copy `UIView` with it's layer or how to remove it from `transitionContext.containerView` without removing it at all? Or may be I did everything wrong in general?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact it was wrong idea to copy view or it's layer. I spent two days solving this problem, but today I just added my `buttonsStackView.layer` as a sublayer to `containerView.layer`. Then, in completion closure of the animate method, I removed it from superLayer and added to my `rootViewController.view.layer`. It works perfectly.

`transitionContext.containerView.layer.addSublayer(buttonsStackViewSnapshot)`

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: duration,
                 animations: {
                   buttonsStackViewSnapshot.frame = finalButtonsFrame
},
                 completion: { (finished) in
                   buttonsStackViewSnapshot.removeFromSuperlayer()
                   toVC.view.layer.addSublayer(buttonsStackViewSnapshot)
                   toVC.view.isHidden = false
                   transitionContext.completeTransition(finished)
})
```